# How to avoid "Numbers stored as text" when exporting to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

When I export a table from Access to Excel, all the numbers show up as text, and have that green arrow on the cell. Is there a way to automatically fix this error, or another way to export that works around the error?

For reference, this is how I export:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, pages(i), outputFileName, True
```

Comment: What is the code you are using to do this? Or is it not VBA?

Comment: @enderland edited it in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your table definition. The only time I get a "numbers stored as text" flag when exporting an Access *table* to Excel is when the table's column is defined as `Text` and it contains (something that Excel has decided is) a number, In that case Excel is correct: It *is* a "number" that is formatted as text because it *is* text (the table definition said so).

If the column *really should* be a `Number` column in the Access table then change it. Alternatively, you can go into `File > Options > Formulas` in Excel and disable "Numbers formatted as text or preceded by and apostrophe" under "Error checking rules".

Comment: yeah I had them all as Text's. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In Excel you can do this by using the Text to Columns feature of the ribbon.

Highlight the entire block of text you want to be numbers
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, you're done.

Im not sure if you want an [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) or [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) way to do this, or do you want [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access) to do something like this before it goes into Excel?

Comment: Preferably in access first... I'd want it to be automatic so that whoever exports the table, will see it just fine in Excel.

Comment: Have you tried to craft a query and then export the results of the query rather than the table. This can give you the results you expect.

Comment: so like make a query that is `SELECT * FROM tblName` and use that in the transferSpreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

Using VBA, format the cell range as "General" ...

range("XYZ").NumberFormat = "General"