# Excel Data type/validation - pulling in the correct data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro. Code part is fairly simple:

```
 Sub Test()
 Worksheet.Range("A1").Value = ws.Range("A2").Value2
 End sub
```

Working just fine for ~6,000 lines. One line is causing problems, formatted like so:

```
12345A0
```

Now, there are quite a few other lines like this. They process just fine. This cell, Excel thinks it's a Number, and flags a warning that "Hey this is a number". It then only pulls in

```
12345
```

and truncates the rest of the cell, seeming to figure "Oh, it's a number, I'm fixing it." But I need the entire ID. What is a simple way to get Excel to think "Hang on, I need to get the actual cell contents" - Is there an easy way to do this? (Programatically - this part is part of code that cycles through different sheets and workbooks given to us, and a manual fix will not work)

Edit: Copying and pasting the cell produces 12345 - the ending is truncated. 
Edit 2: Selecting the data inside of the cell and hitting enter changes the cell to 12345. What's going on Excel? Excel 2010 since this might be relevant

Edit 3: Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.NumberAsText = False doesn't do anything besides remove the flag - Excel is still convinced that it's a number in the cell, and not a string. Nevermind what data type we give it.

Comment: Click on the cell that is coming up wrong.  What is in the formula bar?

Comment: Formula bar for the old data is 12345A0. Formula bar for the cell I'm pasting into is 12345. There is a green highlighted error box on this particular cell "The number in this cell is formatted as text or is preceded by an apostrophe". 6789B1 above it and 369C2 below it are working just fine - and have no green error box

Comment: This thread seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843823/how-to-avoid-numbers-stored-as-text-when-exporting-to-excel - I am testing various ways to automatically trigger that setting, and if it even helps

Comment: You need to post the full code here otherwise you risk a close flag - because you haven't met MCVE requirements: **Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**

Comment: Edited to add sub and endsub, and fix the lines. The issue I'm experiencing is an underlying datatype issue, where for some reason Excel is CONVINCED this is a number, and will change whatever it needs to make it a number. I'm trying to solve this issue.